# Checking if the following language is decideable

Tags: complexity-theory

Input: Deterministic TM - M. 
Question: Is there any input x, such that when M run on x, there are 3 different states of M, that M going throught the first state once, the seconed state twice, and 3 times throught the third state ?

To which complexity class the following problem belonges ? 
A. R 
B. RE\R 
C. co-RE\R 
D. Non of the above

I will be glad if someone can give im a formal proof to this problem, and a tip how to deal with this sort of questions.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with complexity class R, you should always think of the Halting problem. If you can find any algorithm (even if superexponential) to solve the problem, it is in R. If you can deduce the halting problem to your problem, (as in this case), the problem is incomputable (and therefore I think the answer is D).

I'm not sure how a formal proof in this case goes, but the idea is that you want to prove that you can solve the halting problem if you can solve your problem. Now suppose you have a TM and you want to find out if it terminates. We assume that we can solve your problem instance. First, we prepend a Turing machine A before the start state of the halting problem and use the start state of A as the new start state. A is such that no state will be visited exactly once, some state will be visited exactly twice and some state will be visited exactly three times. That part should be trivial. Now, except for the end state of the halting machine, We need to make sure that each state of the halting machine will be visited at least twice. I don't know the details, but this should be possible by having a new arrow from each state to itself and manipulating the symbols to each state so that it needs to go to itself once before it can continue to another state. Now, the only possible state that could be visited exactly once, is the end state. Therefore, if you can solve your problem, you can solve the halting problem. But the halting problem is incomputable, so so is your problem.